# Replace special characters (german umlauts)

Tags: magento-1.9, character-encoding

I need to replace special characters in Magento.

For example:

```
<?php echo $string; //echoes "ausführung"?>
  <?php if (strpos($string,"ü")!==false) 
    {echo "umlaut"}?>
```

My problem is that the if-statement is never true. I also tried to html_entity_decode or something, without a result.

Does anyone know how to replace special characters there?
I need to use the string as a CSS class name and special characters are not allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Mage_Core_Helper_Data::removeAccents($string, $german=false)`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php#L289-L341).

This **should** exactly do what you want, but unfourtunatly there is a bug ...

Setting `$german` to `true` **doesn't work**. If you want to use this, please check this: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/345 and fix this "somehow" (I know ... do not touch core files :P)

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
index dda2bd66e..07dbfd7d5 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
@@ -317,9 +317,9 @@ public function removeAccents($string, $german=false)

             if ($german) {
                 // umlauts
-                $subst = array_merge($subst, array(
+                $subst = array(
                     196=>'Ae', 228=>'ae', 214=>'Oe', 246=>'oe', 220=>'Ue', 252=>'ue'
-                ));
+                ) + $subst;
             }

             $replacements[$german] = array();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)() instead

It replaces your character if found

Comment: doenst work either

Comment: How does your code look like?